# Reorder list by a property I don't have

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a bog-standard list in C#: List (where Channel is a TV channel). Channel is defined as:

```
public class Channel
{
    public int ChannelId { get; set; }
    public string ChannelName { get; set; }
}
```

My ORM populates a list of Channels, which comes from the database in Channel Id order. I need to re-order the list based on a new custom sort property, say ChannelOrder, but I can't modify the underlying database.

Any thoughts on how to do this, without modifying the underlying DB?

So for instance, if I current have coming from the db:

ChannelId =1, ChannelName = "BBC1",  ChannelId =2, ChannelName = "BBC2", ChannelId =3, ChannelName = "ITV"

I might want them ordered as BBC2, BBC1, ITV, basically a custom order.

Comment: Do you have sufficiently few of these that you can do the sorting in-process? That would be reasonably simple.

Comment: what is the rule of ordering?

Comment: Can't you add a Order by clause when you're getting your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're happy to do this in-process (rather than as part of the query) you can use:

```
var orderedChannelNames = new[] { "BBC2", "BBC1", "ITV", ... };
var sorted = unsorted.OrderBy(ch => orderedChannelNames.IndexOf(ch.ChannelName));
```

Alternatively, if you know all the channels in your list will be present:

```
var map = unsorted.ToDictionary(ch => ch.ChannelName);
var sorted = orderedChannelNames.Select(name => map[name]);
```

Comment: Create key lookup, custom order keys only, lookup objects from keys. Pretty decent and simple way to seperate concerns here imo.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: You have the channel names in the right order - you just want to map those to the channel *objects* in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use another class that returns an "attached" property, kind of like attached properties in WPF:

```
public static class ChannelSort
{
    static Dictionary<Channel, int> _dict = new Dictionary<Channel, int>();
    public static int GetSort(this Channel c)
    {
        return _dict[c] //will throw if key's not found,
        //may want to handle it for more descriptive exception
    }
    public static int SetSort(this Channel c, int sort)
    {
        _dict[c] = sort;
    }
}
```

And then you could do this:

```
var result = unsortedList.OrderBy(c => c.GetSort());
```